# Выходит за размер массива

Tags: python, python-3.x

Почему выходит за размер массива? Смотрю по точкам останова, keep,i,dlist[i] или равно или меньше, чем макс.элемент

```
from random import randint

zak= int(input('Количество заказов: '))
n = zak #int(input("Количество дней в дедлайне: "))
lst2 = []
dlst = []
info = []
summ = 0
d = 0

for i in range (n,0,-1):
    k = int(input('Введите кол-во дней в дедлайне:'))
    d+= int(k)
    dlst.append(d)
    for j in range(d):
        lst2.append(i)
lst = [randint (10,100) for fe in range(len(dlst))]

for i in range(len(lst)):
    info.append([lst[i],lst2[i]])
for i in range(n):
    maxnum = 0
    b = 0
    for keep in range(dlst[i]):
        if maxnum <= info[keep][0]: #--[Ошибка]list index out of range--#
            if len(info[keep])<3:
                maxnum = info[keep][0]
                b = keep
        if keep == dlst[i] - 1:
            summ += maxnum
            info[b].append(" - на данном варианте, мы получим максимальную прибыль.")
for i in reversed(info):
    print(*i)
print("Мы получили прибыль: ", summ)
```

Задача о расписании: у программиста есть n заказов. Для каждого заказа известен его
дедлайн, di, это срок, до которого нужно выполнить заказ, и известна стоимость
заказа - ci. На выполнение каждого заказа программист тратит один день, он
начинает выполнять заказы в первый день и заказ с дедлайном di ему нужно
выполнить до конца di дня, то есть, например, если у заказа дедлайн 1, его нужно
выполнить до конца первого дня. Нужно составить оптимальное расписание, то есть
определить, какие заказы программист будет выполнять и в какие дни так, чтобы
заработать как можно больше денег, иначе говоря, нужно максимизировать
суммарную стоимость выполненных заказов

Comment: `info` имеет размер `len(dlst)`, а итерируете вы переменную `keep` по *содержимому* `dlst[i]`, вот `info[keep]` и выходит за размер. Разберитесь где у вас что.

Comment: @CrazyElf это я уже экспериментировал, пытался исправить ошибку.  Но ничего не получилось, я вернул в исходное состояние(как вы указали, было также), а в итоге все равно ошибка.

Comment: Вы хотя бы суть задачи опишите. Сложно давать советы по коду, не понимая суть ваших данных. Можно, конечно, и разобраться самому, но мне лично лениво. А вот вам как автору нужно не лениться и описать нормально задачу. Восстанавливать по коду задачу и алгоритм её решения, чтобы исправить код - это двойная работа, а то и тройная.

Comment: Если вы нормально опишете задачу, я подозреваю вы тогда и сами код тут же исправите, ибо начнёте понимать, где у вас в данных что и почему.

Comment: @CrazyElf задание, которые было у меня я прикрепил. Я разбираюсь уже 4ый час. Сдавать скоро, поэтому решил воспользоваться ухищрением в виде форума.

Answer (score 1):

Если коротко, то ошибка в том, что Вы добавляете в `info` ровно столько списков, сколько у вас заказов. Допустим, три заказа, на первый дается 100 дней. Что будет в таком случае в `info`? Правильно, список из трех списков.
Что же будет в `dlst`? Первый элемент - 100(дней на первый заказ), второй - 100+(сумма дней на первый заказ и на второй) и так до трех. Что это означает?
В строке `for keep in range(dlst[i]):` значение переменной `keep` сначала может доходить до 100, а потом и того больше. А в инфо только три списка, сотни там нет...

Очевидная проблема в том, что Вы и сами запутались. Неочевидная - в коде, потому как и код не очевиден. В лоб решение - это избавиться от больших значений из списка `dlst`, а взять `for keep in range(len(dlst))`. Вот и все, ошибки нет. Но прибыль нулевая.